# Test Slider in Selenium with only one element like volume control

Tags: c#, automated-tests, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I need to test a slider with only one element in selenium (c#). Something like the volume or brightness control.
I have searched on-line and all I could find was with two elements (with Source & Target).
I tried many functions and none of them are working.

```
Actions move = new Actions(driver);
move.DragAndDropToOffset(driver.FindElement(By.Id("someid")), 39, -9).Perform();
```

Can anyone please help me with this? I'm completely new to Selenium and c#.
Let me know if I need to provide more details.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there is only one element? If your slider is dragable along some track like this slider

[image]

with a "slider handle" (an <a/> tag as the box with the value "5ft 5") bounded along a "slider track" (a <div> tag as the long black bar) then the distance offset to move can be calculated.  The following code will in C# will work to move the slider handle a percentage along the slider track, with distance calculated using CSS values.

```
public void SetSliderPercentage(string sliderHandleXpath, string sliderTrackXpath, int percentage)
{
    var sliderHandle = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(sliderHandleXpath));
    var sliderTrack = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(sliderTrackXpath));
    var width = int.Parse(sliderTrack.GetCssValue("width").Replace("px", ""));
    var dx = (int)(percentage / 100.0 * width);
    new Actions(driver)
                .DragAndDropToOffset(sliderHandle, dx, 0)
                .Build()
                .Perform();
}
```